# invalid syntax in def

Tags: python, function

I'm using python and it's always show that invalid syntax. i really don't know how to resolve it please help me

```
nameArr2 = def email_to_full_name(i):

    email1 = "balan.acer@mymail.mapua.edu" 
    email2 = "Kendrick.jason@mymail.mapua.edu" 
    nameArr = [email1, email2] 

nameArr2 = def email_to_full_name(i):
    
    name1 = i.split("@") 
    name2 = name1[0].split(".") fullname = name2[1].upper() + "," + name2[0].upper() nameArr2.append(fullname) 
    
    return fullname print("input output") 
for i in nameArr: 
    length = len(str(i)) print(i[1:length] + " input alan.acer@mymail.mapua.edu endrick.jason@mymail.mapua.edu " + email_to_full_name(i))
```

Comment: Please format your question in a way that doesn't turn it into a jumble of styles. If you need to include a large block of code, enclose it in triple backticks, and make sure you don't change indentation, as indentation is meaningful in Python. Also, if you're getting errors that are part of the problem you're having, please include the full errors in your question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1):

```
email1 = "balan.acer@mymail.mapua.edu" 
email2 = "Kendrick.jason@mymail.mapua.edu" 
nameArr = [email1, email2]

def email_to_full_name(i):
  name1 = i.split("@") 
  name2 = name1[0].split(".") 
  fullname = name2[1].upper() + "," + name2[0].upper() 
  return fullname 

print("input output") 
for i in nameArr: 
  length = len(str(i))
  print(i[1:length], " input alan.acer@mymail.mapua.edu endrick.jason@mymail.mapua.edu ", email_to_full_name(i))
```

Comment: thank you so much. I'm new in python so I really don't know what I'm doing

Comment: @CrabangwelHannaJayne Please provide more info about your input and output in order to improve the code

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can't do like that.

You need to define the function first and then run the function.
As shown below:

```
def email_to_full_name(i):

  name1 = i.split("@") 
  name2 = name1[0].split(".")
  fullname = name2[1].upper() + "," + name2[0].upper() 
  nameArr2.append(fullname) 

  return fullname

print("input output")

nameArr2 = email_to_full_name(I) # replace I with whatever you want to pass in function
```